# Is there a way to write 1/4th of a file into a String buffer?

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, filereader, stringbuffer

I have a piece of code as.

```
File file = new File(path);
FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
String temp;
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
while((temp=br.readLine())!=null){          
   sb.append(temp);
   sb.append(" ");
}
```

This would read every line from a file and store it in a StringBuffer. My file is quite huge, and I have a requirement to multi-thread it so that processing would be faster.
Is there a way to say like I want only 1/4th of the file to be written into the buffer?

I know that I can't say this. But I want something equivalent to this.

```
for(int i=0; i<reader.length/4; i++)
```

Comment: I don't think you can, but if you know how a quarter is ahead of time, you can stop reading at that point.

Comment: What, exactly, does your processing entail?  (What do you do with the data after it's in `StringBuffer`)?

Comment: What do you mean with "quite huge"? Will the file always fit into memory or is it so huge you have to avoid an OutOfMemoryException this way?

Comment: I have a 12GB file. I want the content in 4 StringBuffers using 4 threads, so that the processing efficiency is more. So I thought I could break the contents of a file.

Comment: "My file is quite huge, and I have a requirement to multi-thread it so that processing would be faster": reading data from a file is usually *much* slower than processing it. Are you sure that CPU use is a bottle-neck?

Comment: Do you really need to store the content of the file to process it? Can each line be processed independently? If the lines are dependent, how will you handle cross references between the quarters?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create 1 [file channel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) per thread, and use that at offsets through the file. From a file channel you can get the file's size to work out your splits and set its current location.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't get around this, because you cant read the file concurrently, and if just one thread reads from the stream at a time, this will happen concurrently, nor in parallel. So no benefit there, and apart from this you will have a much more difficult code to write and read, and a lot of thread context switches and thread arbitration, which are not cheap.

What you could do is to instead of writing a big file, write more smaller ones, and if the processing of the read data is time consuming, read a buffer and after that buffer is loaded in memory process it in parallel, this will work out fine.

Also if you are using a single thread, go with StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am running this in a quad core. Excluding the power efficiency factors in manufacturing a substrate, I believe parallel programming is one of the purposes of having multiple cores. Please do correct me if I am wrong.